# Why TableView's FooterView doesn't exist in viewDidLoad() and how to fix it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tablefooterview

I have `tableView` with one section and footer set up in storyboard. I'm trying to change the text in my table's `footerView` in `viewDidLoad()` with following code

```
tableView.footerView(forSection: 0)?.textLabel?.text = "Testing text"
```

but `tableView.footerView(forSection: 0) == nil`

Then on user's tap on a button I call function that changes footerView's text using the same code and it works perfectly.

```
func changeFooterText() {
    tableView.footerView(forSection: 0)?.textLabel?.text = "Testing text after tap"
}
```

Why the `footerView` doesn't exist in `viewDidLoad` and how can I change it's text in `viewDidLoad`? Or should I change it in an other place? When the screen is loaded I need to have the text in footer that depends on other data on the screen.

Looking forward to read your kind advices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use table footer view methods:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: But if I do this - I heed to add styles of footer's label by myself, right? No default styling? And also `tableView.footerView(forSection: 0)` in my function becomes `== nil`.

Answer (score 0):

"viewDidLoad" is too early in the view life cycle. The UITableView has not built it's components yet.

You *might* be able to get away with moving the code to "viewDidAppear", however it would be better to build out your footers and headers the same way you build out other cells. The [dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614975-dequeuereusableheaderfootervieww) delegate method is just for this.

Comment: Thank you! Why do think this way is better then `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?` ?

Comment: Either can work. With viewForFooterInSection you provide a UIView to display in the footer area. The dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier interaction is a bit more like the UITableViewCells themselves, which I find a little nicer. If you have a lot of sections you'll get some object reuse from dequeue...

Comment: Can you please give a code example? It would really help me, I'm very new in iOS development.